# Can gdb step into if 's condition function?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I just wonder how to access if condition function with gdb

### The code is like that:

```
if(loadCatalogue(cat, filename)) {
    printf("Success.\n");
}
else {
    perror("Unable to load catalogue");
}
```

### And gdb shows like that:

```
256     readLine("Enter name of catalogue file to load: ",

(gdb) next

Enter name of catalogue file to load: cat.txt

259     printf("Loading catalogue '%s'...\n", filename);

(gdb) next

Loading catalogue 'cat.txt'...

260     if(loadCatalogue(cat, filename)) {

(gdb) step

261         printf("Success.\n");

(gdb)
```

I want to access that if's condition `loadCatalogue()` but I couldnt do that
is there any way to access that function?

Please let me know how do I handle this.

Comment: Use `step` earlier.  The `printf("Loading catalogue...")` is almost certainly coming from the function you are trying to step into.  The first 'next' in your sample session should probably be 'step'.

Answer (score 3):

The `step` or `s` instruction will step a single line into the function as you desire.  If it appears to skip over the line (as you describe), that means that there are no "lines" in the function to step to -- either because the function is inlined, or because it is in another compilation unit with no debugging information.

In this latter case, you may find the `stepi` (`si`) command useful -- this steps by a single machine instruction.  When you do this, the source line will remain the same, but you are actually part-way into that line.

I find it useful to define an alias in my `.gdbinit` file:

```
define sx
  si
  x /1i $pc
end
document sx
    Step one instruction and print next instruction
end
```

which defines an `sx` command which works just like `si`, but also disassembles the next machine instruction to run afterwards.  So its more like `step` at the machine code level.  Having `nx` which uses `nexti` is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'step' or 's' command in gdb  to get into the function definition.

Comment: i used step but.... it just goes next line. want to get into line260 function loadCatalogue, but couldnt get into function thats why im asking any way to handle this....

Comment: can `stepi` works? I haven't test for it, but I have found the `gdb` have the command, it means `Step one instruction exactly`, not `Step program until it reaches a different source line` which is the description of `s` command.

Comment: I have test for the `s` command, and I found it can step into the function in the if condition, why yours can't?